# jquery toggle is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

javascript file

```
$('#user a').toggle(function(){
    //first function here
    $('#nav #user-menu').show();
    //$('#nav #user .profile, .account, .logout').show();
},
function(){
    // second function here
    $('#nav #user-menu').hide();
    //$('#nav #user .profile, .account, .logout').hide();
});
```

main.html.erb

```
<div id="nav">
    <% if !session[:user_id] %>
    <%= link_to "Please login" , :action => 'login' %>
    <%= link_to "Register", :action => 'register'%>
    <% else %>
    <div id="user"><%= link_to "#{@user.username}"%>
        <div id="user-menu">
            <div class="profile"><%= link_to "Profile" ,:controller => 'users', :action => 'profile'%></div>
            <div class="account"><%= link_to "Account" ,:controller => 'users', :action => 'account'%></div>
            <div class="logout"><%= link_to "Logout" , :action => 'logout'%></div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

on toggling the user-menu div visibility is working properly but on clicking on the profile , logout and other links , they arent functioning as expected but if i remove the toggle condition and visibility from javascript then the link are working just fine
please help

Comment: I've tried passing 2 functions to toggle before as well and it doesn't work.  Apparently it's not supposed to work like that now.

Comment: yea I was tring to find an example where toggle handles 2 functions and no luck there

Answer (score 0):

Try something more like:

```
var makeVisible = true;  // put logic in here to decide whether you want it shown
$("#user-menu").toggle(makeVisible);
```

Comment: visibility is not an issue , but the links on visibility are not functioning